# Understand a search pattern in AWK?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am reading section 2.3 of the tutorial at - http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk_2.html#m2

> There is more to Awk's string-searching capabilities. The search can
>   be constrained to a single field within the input line.

For example:

```
$1 ~ /^France$/
```

There is no code to which shows how this pattern works. Can someone show me how this line can be used and how it works ?

Comment: I don't see any gray highlighting around my code. Why ?

Comment: What on earth makes you think my answer should be downvoted? It's the correct advice for you. Feel free to muddle along in whatever web sites you see fit if you prefer though.

Comment: @anubhava - okay, I did that. Can i be upvoted to 0 ? It would be better if he added an answer or some clue before suggesting the book. The suggestion is good though.

Comment: I've already upvoted you for deleting that offensive comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!

> $1 ~ /^France$/

With the following awk command:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^France$/ { print }'
```

And the following input

```
France 1
France1 2
france 3
- France 4
France - 5
```

The output will be

```
France 1
France - 5
```

`$1` is the value of the first field; the default for awk is to split using whitespace delimited fields.  The `/^France$/` is the regular expression matching the exact string France (using start-of-string and end-of-string anchors `^` and `$`).  And finally, `~`, is a binary string operator that matches the left-hand side by the regular expression on the right-hand side.

Note that regular expressions can be expressed as normal quoted strings or given in variables as well, but the "/.../" syntax is better when the expression is inline as it's more obvious and there's no need for extra escaping that strings cause when there's either a quote or a backslash in the expression.

Of course, that particular expression would be simpler as `$1 == "France"`.

Let me know if a more complex example will help.

Comment: You don't even need the `{print}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't tell you how relieved I am.

Comment: True Kevin - I added that for clarity and to offer an easier model to start from for a beginner.  Glad to help blasto!

Answer (score 1):

To learn awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins. Don't rely on random web sites to have accurate or useful information.

Comment: Hi Ed. Did that code make any sense ? That random website was recommended and upvoted here - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/is-there-a-basic-tutorial-for-grep-awk-and-sed 
But, looks like no one reviews these links. The first part of the tutorial was good though.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. The functionality you'd get from that code is more sensibly written as simply `$1 == "France"` and it talks about string-searching but then it uses an RE-searching construct to demonstrate it. No wonder you're confused!

Comment: Please see the above answer. It works. Please don't delete your answer. Let it be here.

Comment: Of course it works, it's just not how you'd really write the code to provide that functionality. I didn't plan to delete my answer, it's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: I understand its important. But, I only needed a quick primer. The book can come later. So, I was hoping for some decent web site. Would have appreciated the answer more if it solved the problem as well.

Comment: Your question WAS answered, just not in the way you wanted. Clearly you need more than a quick primer or you wouldn't be asking questions like this. If you come to a point in a tutorial that says `$1 ~ /^France$/` and you just CANNOT figure out what that means - that is a clear sign that your tutorial isn't working for you!